# Accessing columns of a matrix or row vector using the same syntax

Tags: matrix, vector

Let's say I wish to retrieve the *i*th column of a matrix `A`.
I can do that using the following syntax;

```
A[[All, i]]
```

My problem is that sometimes `A` is in fact a 1 x *n* matrix, i.e. a row vector, in which case the above syntax will fail with a `Part` error message saying the depth of A is insufficient.

Other than writing additional code trapping the case where `A` is a vector (in which case I just use `A[[i]]`), is there some simple alternative syntax which I could use that is agnostic between whether `A` is a vector or a matrix?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?:

```
getColumn[a_, k_] := Map[#[[k]] &, a, {ArrayDepth[a] - 1}];

vec = Range@5;
mat = Partition[Range@25, 5];
getColumn[vec, 3]
getColumn[mat, 3]
(*
3
{3, 8, 13, 18, 23}
*)
```

Comment: There is a typo - I think you meant `#[[k]]` instead of `#[[3]]`, but thanks.

Comment: @RobertNathaniel Quite right. Copied the test code and forgot to change to the parameter.  An you’re welcome.